# Casting Int as Unsigned Char

Tags: c

I'm trying to read individual bytes of an int in C, but for some reason the following happens:

```
int x = -128;
//this prints 128 255
printf("%d %d\n", ((unsigned char *) (&x))[0], ((unsigned char *) (&x))[3]);
```

Should it not print 128 128 instead?

Comment: What kind of computer are you on? Little endian? Big endian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The representation of `-128` in two's complement is

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000 // 4 bytes
```

The [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)  of a system means the order in which the bytes are stored in memory. Big-endian means that most significant byte, i.e., the first byte, is stored in the smallest address and little endian means that the least significant byte, i.e., the last byte is stored in the smallest address. Your machine is little endian. Therefore, the order of bytes is

```
10000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 // 4 bytes
```

Therefore, `((unsigned char *) (&x))[0]` means the first byte `100000000` and evaluates to `128`. `((unsigned char *) (&x))[3]` means the last byte `11111111` which evaluates to `255`.

Answer (score 2):

It is machine specific and depends upon the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the processor.

<sup>(look into the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) wikipage, it is very well explained; [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) is little-endian.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
Should it not print 128 128 instead?
```

-128 is represented as

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
   [3]     [2]      [1]      [0]
```

when you say `((unsigned char *) (&x))[0]` in case of little endian machine, it will print 
128 cos you are trying to cast (10000000) to `unsigned char` which is 128 and `(unsigned char *) (&x))[3]` would print 255 which is all 1's.